# How can I get a direction vector that's parallel to platform?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, rotation, direction

[image]

I would like to push obj to the edge of platform.
The push power comes from the center of platform.
The platform can rotate or move, so its rotation and position can be changed.

So all I need is the direction vector that's parallel to the platform regardless of the position and rotation of obj and platform.

How can I get this direction vector?
Please help me..

Comment: Is the platform rotated around Y only?

Comment: [`Vector3.ProjectOnPlane`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ProjectOnPlane.html)

Comment: No it can be rotated any direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess that the height of the moved object position from the plane, and the plane pos are known, so find some cool pseudocode.
Remember that a dotProduct is a projection of one vector in the others direction, so, the height of your object to push projected in the plane's normal is:

`Vector3 objHeightProyectedInPlaneNormal = Vector3.Dot((planePos - ObjPos), yourPlaneNormal);`

Green arrow showing `objHeightProyectedInPlaneNormal`:

[image]

The module of that vector upwards from the plane origin, or easier the sum of that vector to the planes position should give you the push direction origin's position:

`Vector3 pushDirOrigin = planePos + objHeightProyectedInPlaneNormal`

Rounded with green `pushDirOrigin`:

[image]

With your object position and the push origin, you have your direction:

`Vector3 pusDir = (ObjPos - pushOrigin).normalized`

Comment: Thank you so much for this vaulable tip! It worked very well. Thank you!

Comment: glad that helped! check also the `Vector3.ProjectOnPlane` suggested in the comments. I think that that would also give you the desired direction directly

Comment: Okay I'll check that function too. Thank you!